# Bump package/bower version based on PR author

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I'm trying to wrap my head around GitHub actions as well as how YAML is parsed.

For obvious reasons, I'd like to make use of actions already available on the marketplace. This is what I have so far..

```
- name: Bump Version

  on:
    pull_request:
      branches:
        - main

  jobs:
    bump-patch:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest

      steps:
        - name: Get current package version
          uses: martinbeentjes/npm-get-version-action@v1.1.0
          with:
            # Path to package.json file (directories only), e.g. packages/mypackage/
            path: ./

        - name: Bump Patch Version
          uses: jessicalostinspace/bump-semantic-version-action@v1.0.1
          with:
            semantic-version: 1.0.0
            version-type: PATCH
```

So a few obvious things.. I need to read the current package/bower version in order to Bump it correctly with the action. I also need to make sure the branch in the PR is the one that gets updated and commits the change to that branch. Additionally the action should only run depending on the user who opened the PR.

---

***The question:***
Is it even possible to do this with GitHub actions or would a github app/service be better suited?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#get-a-pull-request says that there's an `user` and `author_association` attribute in the response - maybe you could check those through the API?